# how to set progress bar to 0

Tags: python, kivy

Value of the progress bar depends on  `My_Numeric_Value` , when i press `set 0` it doesnt work properly.

.kv file:

```
WidgetsExample:

<-MyProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    thickness: 24
    color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.88, 0.56, 0.89, 1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - self.thickness/2
            size: self.width, self.thickness
            radius: [self.thickness/4]
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - self.thickness/2
            size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, self.thickness
            radius: [self.thickness/4]

<WidgetsExample>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(0.71, 0.71, 0.7,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "10dp"
    spacing: "10dp"
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate:root.Text_input_on_text_validate(self)
        size_hint: 1,.5
    MyProgressBar:
        id: my_progress_bar
        thickness: 50
        color: 1, 0, 0.5, 1
        max:100
        value: root.My_numeric_value
        pos_hint: {"center_x" :.5}
        size_hint:.9,.2
    Button:
        text: "set 0"
        size_hint:.2,.2
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        on_press: root.Button_on_press()
    Slider:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        id: my_slider
        value: root.My_numeric_value
        on_value: root.on_slider_value(self)
        min:0
        max:100
```

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty



class WidgetsExample(BoxLayout):
    My_numeric_value = NumericProperty(0)
    
    def on_slider_value(self, widget):
        self.My_numeric_value = int(widget.value)   

    def Button_on_press(self):
        self.My_numeric_value = 0
    def Text_input_on_text_validate(self, widget):
        self.My_numeric_value = int(widget.text)
        print(self.My_numeric_value)

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass



TheLabApp().run()
```

After pressing the button Progress Bar should look like the second bar in the example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyr1e.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `RoundedRectangle` of the scrollbar is not updated when its width or height is set to zero. There is currently an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6056) in this regard.

In the meantime, you can work around the problem by preventing the width from becoming zero with something like:

```
<-MyProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    thickness: 24
    color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.88, 0.56, 0.89, 1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - self.thickness/2
            size: self.width, self.thickness
            radius: [self.thickness/4]
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - self.thickness/2
            size: self.width * ((self.value + 1e-10) / self.max) if self.max else 1e-10, self.thickness
            radius: [self.thickness/4]
```

So, instead of zero, the minimum width will be 10⁻¹² (1e-10/100 = 0.000000000001).